# String together results from sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a database with a bunch of email addresses and I need to format them to be all in one string like the following:

```
toaddress = "name@gmail.com,name1@gmail.com,name2@gmail.com,name3@gmail.com"
```

Current code:

```
string toaddress = "";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM dbo.Members", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        toaddress = rdr["email"].ToString();
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```

Comment: Make the 'toaddress' a List<string> and use toaddress.Add each time you read one.  Then you can use `string.Join`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string toaddress = null;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM dbo.Members", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        sb.Append(rdr["email"].ToString() + ",");
    }
    rdr.Close();
}

toaddress = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Remember to `Trim` `,` from the end of string using `String.TrimEnd`

Its better if you use `using` statement on your `Command` and `DataReader` object, something like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM dbo.Members", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                sb.Append(rdr["email"].ToString() + ",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: won't that create unnecessary strings with the + in the append call's parameter?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, what do you mean by unnecessary strings ? `,` is required in the output

Comment: @Habib I think he's talking about the string concatenation

Comment: That's not a level of optimization you should generally be worried about. See also http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: But if he already turned to using StringBuilder, it'll be consequent to use `sb.Append(rdr["email"]).Append(",")`

Comment: @okrumnow, sure that can be done, But I suspect if it would give any extra benefit it term of performance. \

Answer (score 3):

Switch toaddress to a `List<string>` like so:

```
List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
```

Use `add` when you get it:

```
addresses.Add(rdr["email"] as string));
```

Then at the end use `string.Join`

```
var toaddress = string.Join(",", addresses);
```

#### *EDIT*

Suggestion two, to avoid iterating twice:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetEmails()
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
  {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM dbo.Members", conn);
      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (rdr.Read())
      {
          toaddress = rdr["email"].ToString();
      }
      rdr.Close();
  }
}
```

Then simply call: `string.Join(",", GetEmails())`

This way if you want to do crazy stuff with it you can, a la:

```
string.Join(",", GetEmails().Select(email => email.ToLower()).Distinct())
```

To make all the emails lower case and distinct (for instance).

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Other than it does not copy+paste the complete code, this is fine.

Comment: Very confused right now...this solves the problem, and it even models it correctly, allowing the questioner to use the `List<string>` the right way.

Comment: Confused as well. Three of us posted more or less this same answer at the same time. We can't all be wrong ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I think `string.Join` is probably unnecessary. You will end up **iterating twice**, once for creating a `List<string>` and then in `string.Join`.

Comment: @Habib that's true, but it doesn't matter. Only one of those is even remotely time consuming. Database access is like mail-ordering lettuce, iterating an in-memory list of strings is like grabbing the lettuce in your fridge.

Comment: @Habib if you're truly concerned about that then you could factor it out into a function returning an IEnumerable<string>, yield returning rdr["email"] as string each time...then it'll iterate once.

Answer (score 1):

With Sql Server (2008 sure, seems to be in 2005 but not sure), you can use FOR XML to concatenate all rows with ',' as separators and STUFF to remove the first ',':

```
select stuff((select ',' +email 
              from Members
              for XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your current string. To get it to work you need to append to it like

```
toaddress += "," + rdr["email"].ToString();
```

However, that's an ugly way. You're better of putting the result in a List first and using string.Join

```
List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
... database stuff    
while (rdr.Read())
{
  addresses.Add(rdr["email"].ToString());
}
... stuff
string toaddress = string.Join(",", addresses)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `List` and use `string.Join` to combine the items together.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM dbo.Members", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        items.Add(rdr["email"].ToString());
    }
    rdr.Close();
}

toaddress = string.Join(",", items);
```

If you are using the 3.5 framework you need to `ToArray()` your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var toaddress = new StringBuilder();
var delimiter = "";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM dbo.Members", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        toaddress.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", delimiter, rdr["email"].ToString());
        delimiter = ",";
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
return toaddress.ToString();
```